# How to perform mapping values in jolt

Tags: transformation, jolt

I am trying to perform conditional mapping of values from the following JSON.

My input,

```
   {
  "rating": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "locations": [
        {
          "num": 1
        },
        {
          "num": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
  {
  "rating": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "locations": [
        {
          "num": 1
        }
      ],
      "new_locations": [
        {
          "num": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My spec,

```
  [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "rating": {
        "*": {
          "locations": {
            "*": {
              "num": "@(3,id)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

If the num value matches with id,then it should stay in location array else should be moved to new_locations.

Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do that kind of conditional matching logic with the "out of the box" Jolt transforms.